# Why std::string concatenation operator works like right-associative one?

Tags: c++, string, gcc, visual-c++-2012

Running the following MWE extracted from my pet project and compiled with GCC 4.9.1 (and 4.8.1 also)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class InputStringStream
{
public:
    InputStringStream(const std::string& str) : istringstream(str), currentLine() {}
    std::string readLine()
    {
        std::getline(istringstream, currentLine);
        return currentLine;
    }

private:
    std::istringstream istringstream;
    std::string currentLine;
};

int main()
{
    std::string s = std::string("line1\nline2\nline3");
    InputStringStream stream(s);
    std::cout << stream.readLine() + "\n" + stream.readLine() + "\n" + stream.readLine() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

produces the following output

```
line3
line2
line1
```

while I expect

```
line1
line2
line3
```

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. The same code compiled with Apple LLVM compiler version 5.1 produces what I expect. Visual C++ 2012 is on GCC side.

Comment: Just to restate the point: Your question itself is incorrectly mixing up two unrelated issues: The associativity of an operator determines the *meaning* of an expression (its parse tree, if you will), but the problem you're encountering is about the *order of evaluation of subexpressions*. The two have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes, now I understand that. But when I asked the question I thought (wrongly) that the issue is about associativity of operator+(). So I will leave it as it is, it may help someone else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is *unspecified*, so what you're doing wrong is holding mistaken, unwarranted beliefs and expectations. (Overloaded operators like `+` and `<<` are just ordinary function calls.)

You have to extract the stream elements in a deterministic order, and it's *your* responsibility to do so. For example:

```
std::cout << stream.readLine() + '\n';
std::cout << stream.readLine() + '\n';
std::cout << stream.readLine() + '\n';
```

Even better, avoiding redundancy and temporary strings:

```
for (auto i : { 1, 2, 3 }) { std::cout << stream.readLine() << '\n'; }
```

Comment: Got it! Did not write in C++ for years and forgot almost everything... :(

Comment: That for-Loop is so sexy compared to `for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)`

Comment: @iFreilicht Really? I prefer a good ol' for when I need a good ol' for.

Comment: Of course, somebody will change it to `: {1,2,4}` one day and much confusion ensues.

Comment: @MSalters: I was considering the ability to switch from arithmetic to geometric a feature, not a defect!

Comment: @Ven To each its own. `loop(3)` would be even more convenient, but I guess we can't have that in C++

Comment: @iFreilicht `#define loop(n) { int __m = n; for (var i = 0; i < __m; ++i)` there you have it :P. (sorry, sorry)

Answer (score 11):

The problem is not about associativity, in this expression:

```
stream.readLine() + "\n" + stream.readLine() + "\n" + stream.readLine()
```

It's unspecified which `stream.readLine()` is called first.

Comment: The "sequence points" themselves aren't the real issue. The readline calls are not mixed. One completes before the other one starts. In C++11, terms, one call is sequenced-before the other. The real issue is that it's unspecified which one goes first.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you're doing wrong is assuming that in an expression in which you call `stream.readLine()` three times, the order of appearances of those expressions matches the order of calls. Some compilers may evaluate the last of the calls first, some may evaluate them in order. In theory, some might even evaluate the middle one first. This is just a general rule of C++: the order of evaluation of an expression is unspecified.

A simple way to get the same results on all implementations is to store the three results in separate variables.

Comment: One compiler may evn sometimes evaluate one expression first, sometimes another. Not only for identical looking code, but for the same code.

Comment: @gnasher729 Sure. A realistic scenario on current implementations is if it happens in a function that gets inlined, where depending on the caller, one argument may sometimes be easier to evaluate first, sometimes harder.